# Retrieving 2 separate portions of a text in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a page in Wordpress containing a text with 5 paragraphs. Each paragraph is separated by a `<!--more-->`.

Now I need to retrieve the first the 2 first paragraphs to display on my front_page.php, each paragraph in a different `<section>`

What I am using now is the following:

in functions.php

```
function split_content() {

     global $more;
    $more = true;
    $content = preg_split('/<span id\=\"(more\-\d+)"><\/span>/', get_the_content('Read more...'), 0);
    for($c = 0, $csize = count($content); $c < $csize; $c++) {
        $content[$c] = apply_filters('the_content', $content[$c]);
    }
    return $content;
}
```

in front_page.php

```
          <div>

            <?php               

            $my_query = new WP_Query( 'page_id=26' );
             if ($my_query->have_posts()):$my_query->the_post();



            $content = split_content(); 

            ?>


            <?php echo array_shift($content);?>             

        </div>

         <div>   


            <?php echo array_shift($content);?>
            <?php endif; ?>

    </p>
    </div>
```

I am getting the right output for the first div and for the second div I am getting the rest of the text (total text - first paragraph)

Anyone could suggest some explanation please, I am quite new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem, then there is a much easier solution, you can just use the read more function in the text editor within the post, and display the_content within your loop. here is a reference. [The Content function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content)

So forget about the split_content function, and within your query, literally just use the function the_content, and then in the post, set your read more seperator after that second paragraph.

Comment: Thank you very much for your great help. How could i retrieve the text before the 2nd <--more--> tag and ignoring the first one?

Comment: You need to remove all of those more tags except for one, under the 2nd paragraph. Then to seperste them into sections. Just use HTML markup in the text editor within the page. Your question is a bit vague so I'm not sure if this fully answers it but it should work if your just trying to print 2 of the 5

Comment: I need to print the 1st and the 2nd text before the <--more--> tag, but each in a different place and section.

Comment: And you can't do that within the Wordpress text editor? If your doing this within a post or page, you shouldn't have a problem doing it within the text editor. If it's on the home page then you should be using custom fields or custom post types. Not a page, or even two seperate posts within a new category.